# GMP mpz_array_init is an obsolete function - How should we initialize mpz arrays?

Tags: c, gmp

Having only used the [GNU MP Bignum Library](https://gmplib.org/index.html#dir) a few times, I was interested to see that the way I had previously allocated/initiated arrays is now obsolete. From [Integer Special Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Special-Functions.html#Integer-Special-Functions):

> 5.16 Special Functions
>
> The functions in this section are for various special purposes. Most
>   applications will not need them. — Function: void mpz_array_init
>   (mpz_t integer_array, mp_size_t array_size, mp_size_t fixed_num_bits)
>
> ```
> This is an obsolete function. Do not use it.
> ```

This is how I would allocate and initialze an array of `mpz_t`.

```
int array_size = 100;
mpz_t *num_arr;
num_arr = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(mpz_t));
mpz_array_init(*num_arr, array_size, 1024);
```

This still works without and error or warning, btw, but now that this function is listed as obsolete, what is the proper way to allocate an array using GMP in C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply loop over the array elements and initialize them one by one using `mpz_init2` if you want to preallocate memory:

```
for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    mpz_init2(num_arr[i], 1024);
}
```

The problem with `mpz_array_init` is that it would never release the allocated memory. If you initialize the elements separately, you can free them afterwards:

```
for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    mpz_clear(num_arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: What about free(num_arr) at the end, can I use that instead of going through the array with mpz_clear?

Comment: No, `mpz_clear` is needed to free the memory allocated for each `mpz_t`. Additionally, you have to call `free(num_arr)` to free the array.

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html), calling `mpz_init2` instead of `mpz_init` is "never necessary; reallocation is handled automatically by GMP when needed."

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII But as the next paragraph says, it avoids reallocations if the size is known in advance.

Answer (score -1):

What about different method :

```
/*
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/large-array-in-gmp
gcc a.c -lgmp
*/
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

#define LENGTH 100000

int main ()
{       
      /* definition */
    mpz_t *A;
    mpz_t temp;

    mpz_init(temp);

    /* initialization of A */
    A = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(mpz_t));
    if (A==NULL) {
          printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
          return 1;
                 }
    // assign
    mpz_set_ui(temp, 121277777777777777); // using temp var 
    mpz_set(A[4], temp);
    mpz_set_str(A[5], "19999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999992",10); // using string if number > max 

     // check
    gmp_printf ("%Zd\n",A[4]); // 
    gmp_printf ("%Zd\n",A[5]); // 


    /* no longer need A */
   free(A);
   mpz_clear(temp);

        return 0;
}
```

Is it good ?

Comment: No, you are using mpz_set / mpz_set_str without calling mpz_init on those variables first.