# How can I completely free the memory allocated for array/vector of GMP mpz_t/mpz_class?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, gmp

I need to handle the large array of `mpz_t` and release the memory afterwords. However, when profiling the RSS at each stage with `htop` command, `mpz_clear` does not seem to free the memory completely.

Here's the sample C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void) {
    mpz_t *A;
    int size = 1<<20;
    A = (mpz_t *) malloc(size*sizeof(mpz_t));
    getchar(); // RSS=876KB

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        mpz_init_set_ui(A[i],0);
    }
    getchar(); // RSS=50MB

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        mpz_clear(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    getchar(); // RSS=34MB!!

    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26910710/6796582), the memory deallocation process above (i.e. call `mpz_clear` on `mpz_t` elements & `free` array) is properly done.

I also tried with the vector of `mpz_class` C++ wrapper as follows, which resulted in the same situation.

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<mpz_class> A;
    int size = 1 << 20;
    A.reserve(size);
    std::cin.ignore();

    for (int i=0; i<(size); i++) {
        A.emplace_back(0);
    }
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::vector<mpz_class>().swap(A);
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to release the whole memory allocated for an `mpz_t` array?

### Update

Thanks to the comment section I've learnt that [`free` does not necessarily release the memory back to the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139436/why-free-doesnt-really-frees-memory). But in my case, using glibc on Ubuntu 16.04, `free()` **does** release the amount of memory reserved by `malloc` (i.e 16*2^20 = 16MB, assuming that `sizeof(mpz_t)` is 16-byte) because it exceeds the default [`M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) value (=128KB).

So I suspect that there is still some orphaned memory implicitly allocated by GMP (≈32MB in the above example) and `free()` needs to be called on it separately.

Comment: Why don't you use the C++ API for GMP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139436/why-free-doesnt-really-frees-memory ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why free() doesn't really frees memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139436/why-free-doesnt-really-frees-memory)

Comment: @KerrekSB I did. Please look at the second sample code.

Comment: Ah, yes. Your system allocator probably just doesn't return memory to the OS. Which allocator are you using?

Comment: @AkiraTakahashi -- What would the results be if you called `malloc`, and then immediately called `free()`?  Would your results be the same?  If so, then the issue has nothing to do with `gmp`, but how the heap manager handles the memory.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm using glibc's malloc on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It wasn't the same (either with `calloc`). `free` immediately returned the memory to the OS. Additionally, I experimented with an array/vector of `uint64_t` but the allocated memory was completely released back in this case.

Comment: Big chunks are usually allocated by a different method, and *are* released back to the OS. You probably shouldn't care about any of this unless you are writing your own allocator.

Comment: malloc followed immediately by free won't necessarily be reflected in the RSS. Watching RSS is not a good way to understand your heap performance.